# Find the next number here

Tags: sequences-and-series

27 , 49 , 45 , 100 , 65 , ?

The options given are:
329, 225, 324, 400

All I can conclude is that the answer is a square of some number, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I can't answer the question unless you showed your work.

Comment: The pattern I noticed is that it is an alternate series. 2nd, 4th... will be perfect squares. I can't find the relation between those or between the 1st and 3rd

Comment: One can generate a representing polynomial for each one of these options: see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%5B27+,+49+,+45+,+100+,+65,+329%5D), [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%5B27+,+49+,+45+,+100+,+65,+225%5D), [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%5B27+,+49+,+45+,+100+,+65,+324%5D) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%5B27+,+49+,+45+,+100+,+65,+400%5D).

Comment: That is best for a last resort. Did you recognize any other pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could certainly justify more than one answer, but here's one that seems likelier than many to be the desired answer: each number in an even position is the square of half the product of the digits of the preceding number. That would make it $225$.

**Added:** That is, the first number is $27$; half the product of its digits is $\frac12\cdot2\cdot7=7$, and the next number is $7^2=49$. The third number is $45$; half the product of its digits is $\frac12\cdot4\cdot5=10$, and the next number is $10^2=100$. The fifth number is $65$; half the product of its digits is $\frac12\cdot6\cdot5=15$, so if the pattern holds, I’d expect the next number to be $15^2=225$.

Comment: that's a great observation

Comment: yes I understood it right after I wrote the comment. Now it's clear. Thanks

Comment: @Kushal: You’re welcome.